# Преобразовать строку в список

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, список

У меня есть строка (string):

```
a = '"'"smth"'", "'"smth1"'", "'"smth2"'"' # и так далее
print(a)
>>>'smth', 'smth1', 'smth2'
```

Как превратить это в list, чтобы каждое слово было по-отдельности?
Вот так:

```
['smth','smth1', 'smth2']
```

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь [ast.literal_eval()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
In [16]: import ast

In [17]: a = list(ast.literal_eval(a))

In [18]: a
Out[18]: ['smth', 'smth1', 'smth2']
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно так попробовать, без импортов:

```
a.replace("\"", "").split(", ")
```

Answer (score 1):

Ваша строка напоминает командную строчку, можно [`shlex` модуль](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html) попробовать:

```
>>> import shlex
>>> s = '"smth", "smth1", "smth2"'
>>> shlex.split(s)
['smth,', 'smth1,', 'smth2']
```

Запятые, если не нужны, можно убрать с помощью: `.rstrip(',')` метода на каждом элементе.